# New to java, don't understand why my while loop program will not run

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, percentage

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

"Mexico's population is 62 million and is growing at the annual rate of 7%. The United States' current population is 280 million and is growing at the annual rate of 2%. If these two countries were to maintain their current rates of growth, in how many years will Mexico's population be more than half that of the United States? Your program should answer this question."

okay so this is the code that I have so far. when I run the program I get this error.

Not really sure how to fix it. Can anyone help out? :/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Whatever {

 public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

  int mex = 62000000;
  int usa = 280000000;
  int years = 0;
  double t = 0 ;

   while(mex(Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa(Math.pow(1.02, t)))
   {
       t++;
       years = t;
       if (mex > (usa * 0.5));
          break;
  }   

       System.out.println ("Mexicos population is half of America in " + years + "years");
    }   

   }
```

***EDIT***

for anyone wondering I ended up getting the code to work. this is the code.

---

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Whatever {

public static void main (String [] args){

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

double mex = 62000000;
double usa = 280000000;
double years = 0;

    while(mex <= usa/2) 
    {   
        years++;
    mex = mex * 1.07;
    usa = usa * 1.02;

    }       
    System.out.println ("Mexicos population is half of America in " + years + " years ");
    }
```

}

Comment: What are `mex` and `usa` supposed to be? (In the condition of your while-loop)

Comment: For future reference - we don't want errors as screenshots. Please copy/paste the output into your question and ensure the formatting is bearable.

Comment: If you don't know how to copy text from the command prompt, one way is to right click in the window -> mark. Then highlight the text and right click in the window again to copy.

Comment: mex = mexico's population
usa = USA's population

Comment: You're not tracking population growth.  Your `mex` and `usa` never change, so you keep comparing the same values.

Comment: Your syntax in using Math.pow function is all screwed up. See (for example) here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that after running the program. I thought the t++ would make it so it would change? How would I fix that?

Comment: @AntonPipenbacher `t` changes, but your `mex` and `usa` don't, so break never fires

Comment: I can see when I run the program that it does not work but I'm still confused as to why. if the t changes by 1 everytime the loop runs wouldn't that change what 1.07^t equals. Then that would run the program until mex >= 1/2 the usa's population?

Answer (score 3):

mex is an integer.

I think you were trying to multiply.

Use mex * (Math.pow(1.07, t), if you want to multiply.

Comment: this is the essential answer - I think some other answers are speaking only about methods since they didn't wait to think a bit about what OP was trying to do.

Comment: okay, for some reason I just assumed you could say usa(Math.pow(whatever)). I fixed that up pretty esily

Comment: @AntonPipenbacher that still doesn't fix the code, it's just a beginning. Like it was already said, you keep comparing the same values within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
while(mex(Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa(Math.pow(1.02, t)))
```

Putting parentheses right after a variable signals to Java that you're trying to call the function with that name (in this case `mex` and `usa`). What **you're** actually trying to do is multiply those values, so you need asterisks in there:

```
while(mex*(Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa*(Math.pow(1.02, t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you define several variables:

```
int mex = 62000000;
int usa = 280000000;
int years = 0;
double t = 0 ;
```

However, you try to use these as functions:

```
while(mex(Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa(Math.pow(1.02, t)))
```

In Java, these variables are used as arguments for functions; not the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

You have applied parenthesis to the "`mex`" expression in your while loop (as if it were a function), where "`mex`" is just a regular variable. Same thing for your use of "usa"..

```
while(mex(Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa(Math.pow(1.02, t)))
         ^^^               ^
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to do multiplication you need to use the `*`, ie

```
 while(mex * (Math.pow(1.07, t)) <= usa * (Math.pow(1.02, t)))
```